# Odd behavior in Qiskit's circuit <-> Clifford tableau functionality

Tags: qiskit, stabilizer-code, clifford-group

I noticed a strange behavior as I tried to familiarize myself with Qiskit's stabilizer functionalities:

```
import qiskit

qc = qiskit.QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.h(1)
qc.cz(0, 1)
qc.y(0)
qc.cz(0, 1)
cliff = qiskit.quantum_info.Clifford(qc)
```

Next, I compute two state vectors; once directly from *qc* and once from *cliff*.

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
sv = Statevector.from_instruction(qc)
svcl = Statevector.from_instruction(cliff)
```

I'd expect that those two state vectors would be the same, however:

```
print(sv)
Statevector([0.-0.5j, 0.+0.5j, 0.-0.5j, 0.-0.5j],
            dims=(2, 2))
```

and

```
print(svcl)
Statevector([-0.35355339+0.35355339j,  0.35355339-0.35355339j,
             -0.35355339+0.35355339j, -0.35355339+0.35355339j],
            dims=(2, 2))
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: The two vectors differ by just a global phase factor.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in behavior arises from how `Statevector.from_instruction()` treats a `QuantumCircuit` object (by simulating the circuit) versus a Clifford object (by assuming it represents a unitary operator). If you want to obtain the state vector resulting from simulating a circuit, you should use `Statevector.from_instruction(qc)` directly on the `QuantumCircuit` object.